# Wrong logo path in email emails

Tags: magento2

I'm using **Magento ver. 2.3.2-p2** I have set document root /pub folder in my Apache, Now in my transaction logo  is no working due to wrong path:

Current : https://www.msite.com/pub/media/email/logo/stores/1/payment.png

Expected : https://www.msite.com/media/email/logo/stores/1/payment.png

Any solution for it?

Comment: magento 2 root you cerate media folder ?? But 'pub/media' folder logo path correct way i think